# How to handle white spaces in lexer implemented as finite automata?

Tags: compiler-construction, whitespace, lexer, automata

I created lexer for one simple programming language. Now instead of regular expressions (RegEx in Java) I use deterministic finite automata. The automata works great except it would not report error for example if I had moduleclouds (both module and clouds are keywords) in source code. Instead it would create two tokens called KW_MODULE and KW_CLOUDS. One could argue that I could look ahead for white space if the automata is in final state for KW_MODULE. But that would not solve the problem, because in the language I could have something like 8-6 (not separated by white spaces) which would correctly be translated into tokens INT DASH INT.

I know that it is not good idea for handling white spaces in the grammar of the parser.

My automata is implemented as matrix (rows are states, and columns are characters from the alphabet, cells are transition states). When the automata goes in final state I reset the automata to start from the start state.

I believe the problem is because this programming language does not use semi-colons. For example:

module;
clouds;

instead it uses white space for separating the lines:
module
clouds

Thanks in advance.

Regards.

Comment: Don't. Please, I have work with programming languages like yours. I suggest NOT to use rows, columns, or spaces, for a new programming language, its make life difficult for users of your programming language

Comment: "I believe the problem is because this programming language does not use semi-colons." No, it is because you have mis-implemented your lexer. Practically every extant programming language above assembler level uses spaces to separate tokens. You've done something wrong. Without knowing what you did it is impossible to say what you did wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My lexer does not directly handle white spaces (I don't have white space in the alphabet of the lexer). I did this on purpose to simplify the lexer. But as it came out it is a must. The problem is that some tokens does not require white space between them as I stated above. So I need to incorporate white space for some tokens but not necessarily for others. For ex. for KW_ENV I should make reg. ex. ( environment ) or (environment ) and for INT, ( INT ) or (INT) or ( INT) or (INT ). Thanks for making me figure it out. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, the parsers that I've worked on deal with this problem by demanding that keywords are also proper identifiers as defined by the grammar.

So e.g. if you have identifiers defined as a character optionally followed by more characters or digits, any keyword must also fit in that mold. The lexer then only considers a token as a potential keyword if it has already been categorized as an ident.

I would be interested to hear how others deal with this problem, though.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know what you mean, but I forgot to mention that the source code has two parts: environment (where you define clouds, aeroplane, landing field, tracks etc...) and then comes the source code with moving around the plane, statements, identifiers etc... So in the environment there are not any identifiers and therefore moduleclouds would not be recognized as identifier.